# Unable to post my question because it is not properly formatted

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown, quality-filter

I've seen this question asked and answered various times, but I can't solve it with the given information. I have code that displays just as I want it in the preview. But more than an hour of trying various stuff, I'm still stuck. The system will not let me submit my question and claims it is not properly formatted. What can I do differently?

**Here is what the Markdown syntax looks like:**

First bit of code:

<kbd>[image: First bit of code]</kbd>

Second bit of code:

<kbd>[image: Second bit of code]</kbd>

**Here is the rendered preview:**

First bit of code:

<kbd>[image: First bit of code]</kbd>

Second bit of code:

<kbd>[image: Second bit of code]</kbd>

Comment: Can you make it clearer how you want it to display? At the moment we don't really know how to help you as you have not said what the purpose of the image is etc. There are also four images uploaded and only two shown in the question.

Comment: I think it may be in the bit which is being rendered as a quote near the start.

Comment: Rather than an *image* of the markdown, it would have been better to post the actual markdown here. Oh well, I think you have a fair question. I assume an earlier revision was so unclear that it attracted 5 close votes. I've improved it even more and cast a vote to reopen. Hopefully we can get you some help. It looks like you are trying hard; thanks for that!

Comment: I don't know.  How about you only format the code and try to submit?  Stop with the fancy shmancy jiggerypokery as it might confuse the confuser.  Then, after you get the question to post, go and edit it.  Add a bit more of your flourishes.  You might get them all back in.  Or you might find the one that triggers the block.

Comment: Thank you all for putting effort in my post, I will take it with me in future questions. For now getting rid of the bit showing as quote near the start did the truck. Thanks John Palmer